# Optimizing loop

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, optimization

I'm trying to implement a tool that groups certain strings based on the lemmas of their words. During the initialization I make a dictionary for each possible group containing a list of words that would group into this key. This is what I have so far:

```
public Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> Sets { get; set; }

private void Initialize(IStemmer stemmer)
{
    // Stemming of keywords and groups
    var keywordStems = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    var groupStems = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    foreach (string keyword in Keywords)
    {
        keywordStems.Add(keyword, CreateLemmas(keyword, stemmer));
        foreach (string subset in CreateSubsets(keyword))
        {
            if (subset.Length > 1 && !groupStems.ContainsKey(subset))
            {
                groupStems.Add(subset, CreateLemmas(subset, stemmer));
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialize all viable sets
    // This is the slow part
    foreach (string gr in groupStems.Keys)
    {
        var grStems = groupStems[gr];
        var grKeywords = new HashSet<string>((from kw in Keywords
                                                where grStems.All(keywordStems[kw].Contains)
                                                select kw));
        if (grKeywords.Count >= Settings.MinCount)
        {
            Sets.Add(gr, grKeywords);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can speed the bottleneck of this method up?

Comment: First determine if this even *is* a bottleneck. Thus you should measure how long this code really takes. Do you really want to put effort in something that brings you just a few milliseconds?

Comment: This is indeed a bottleneck. With 5k+ strings this particular part is what takes 90% of the running time.

Comment: How long does the code take? How long do you want it to take?

Comment: You obviously have a List or Set of Keywords. Why not precompute the data, save it in a DB and just load it? Missing keywords could be added on miss and saved for future use ...

Comment: With 3500 strings it takes roughly 24 seconds where this part of the code is responsible for 21 of those. By changing the List to a HashSet I managed to scrape of around 7 seconds. Thank you!

Comment: What is the target speed? At what point will you say it is 'fast enough'?

Comment: It is supposed to be used as a web service, so the faster the merrier. Ideally this methods runtime would be below 10 seconds for this amount of strings.

Comment: @EricLippert Oh, that was some leftover code. I've deleted that part now. Thanks.

Comment: I've added your suggestion, unfortunately I didn't see any remarkable speed improvements. Sets is a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>`

Comment: The lemmas are logically a *set* of strings, not a list, right?  Order is unimportant, no duplicates?  Because if that's the case then yes, you can probably get a big speedup in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion would be to change:

```
var keywordStems = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

to:

```
var keywordStems = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
```

That should have an impact due to your later `Contains` call:

```
var grKeywords = new HashSet<string>((from kw in Keywords
                                                where grStems.All(keywordStems[kw].Contains)
                                                select kw));
```

because `Contains` is generally faster on a `HashSet` than a `List`.

Also consider changing:

```
foreach (string gr in groupStems.Keys)
{
    var grStems = groupStems[gr];
    var grKeywords = new HashSet<string>((from kw in Keywords
                                            where grStems.All(keywordStems[kw].Contains)
                                            select kw));
    if (grKeywords.Count >= Settings.MinCount)
    {
        Sets.Add(gr, grKeywords);
    }
}
```

to:

```
foreach (var entry in groupStems)
{
    var grStems = entry.Value;
    var grKeywords = (from kw in Keywords
                                          where grStems.All(keywordStems[kw].Contains)
                                          select kw).ToArray();
    if (grKeywords.Length >= Settings.MinCount)
    {
        Sets.Add(entry.Key, new HashSet<string>(grKeywords));
    }
}
```

By shifting the `HashSet` initialization (which is relatively expensive compared to initializing an `Array`) **into** the `if` statement then you may improve performance **if** the `if` is entered relatively rarely (in your comments you state it is entered roughly 25% of the time).

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @mjwills is a good idea. It seems likely that this is the most expensive operation:

```
var grKeywords = new HashSet<string>((
  from kw in Keywords
  where grStems.All(keywordStems[kw].Contains)
  select kw));
```

The suggestion is to optimize the Contains by taking advantage of the fact that the stems are a set.  But if they're a set then why are we repeatedly asking for containment at all?  **They're a set; do set operations**. The question is "what are the keywords such that every member of the grStem set is *contained within* the keyword's stem set". "Is every member of this set contained in that set" is the *subset* operation.

```
var grKeywords = new HashSet<string>((
  from kw in Keywords
  where grStems.IsSubsetOf(keywordStems[kw])
  select kw));
```

The implementation of IsSubsetOf is optimized for common scenarios like "both operands are sets". And it takes early outs; if your group stems set is *larger* than the keyword stem set then you don't need to check every element; one of them is going to be missing. But your original algorithm checks every element anyways, even when you could bail early and save all that time.

Comment: Thank you! Changing to `IsSubsetOf` scraped off another 3 seconds.

Comment: Great answer - thanks @EricLippert ! `IsSubsetOf` looks perfect for this scenario, I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

And again @mjwills has a good idea which I'll suggest some possible improvements to. The idea here is to execute the query, cache the results in an array, and only later realize it as a hash set, if necessary:

```
foreach (var entry in groupStems)
{
    var grStems = entry.Value;
    var grKeywords = (WHATEVER).ToArray();
    if (grKeywords.Length >= Settings.MinCount)
        Sets.Add(entry.Key, new HashSet<string>(grKeywords));
}
```

First: I actually doubt that avoiding the unnnecessary hash set construction by replacing it with unnecessary array constructions is a win. Measure it and see.

Second: ToList can be faster than ToArray because a list can be constructed before you know the size of the query result set. ToArray basically has to do a ToList first, and then copy the results into an exactly-sized array. So if ToArray is not a win, ToList might be. Or not. Measure it.

Third: I note that the whole thing can be rewritten into a query should you prefer that style.

```
var q = from entry in groupStems
        let grStems = entry.Value
        let grKeywords = new HashSet<string>(WHATEVER)
        where grKeywords.Count >= Settings.MinCount
        select (entry.Key, grKeywords);
var result = q.ToDictionary( ... and so on ... )
```

That's probably not faster, but it might be easier to reason about.

Comment: `I actually doubt that avoiding the unnnecessary hash set construction by replacing it with unnecessary array constructions is a win.` It very much depends on the cost of instantiating the `List` / `Array` vs the `HashSet` (I suspect `HashSet` will be relatively slow due to the `GetHashCode` calls?), and the proportion of times the `if` gets invoked. But, as you say, measurement is the key here. And great point re: `ToList` vs `ToArray`!